# Jenkinsfile how to grep file name in variable

Tags: grep, jenkins-pipeline

I have file in different server and that name will change.
`File: testfile-1.2-12345.sh` ,`"12345"` is going to change.

How I get chancing text to variable?

In server machine this works and it's prints `12345`:

```
ls ~/test/testfile* | awk -F'[-.s]' '{print $5}'
```

But when I do it from jenkins it wont work:

```
def versio = sh "ssh user@${ip} ls ~/test/testfile* | awk -F'[-.s]' '{print \$5}'"
```

It prints `"12345"` but if I try to print `${versio}` it shows `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your command is correct. But in pipeline you need to specify `returnStdout:true`. Detailed documentation is [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script).

```
def versio = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'ssh user@${ip} ls ~/test/testfile* | awk -F\'[-.s]\' \'{print \\$5}\''
```

Comment: def versio = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'ssh user@${ip} ls ~/test/testfile* | awk -F\'[-.s]\' \'{print \$5}\'' ,
I get still error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known

Comment: Beginning of jenkinsfile. def version is inside stage. ssh has worked in other steps

Comment: Is `${ip}` bash or pipeline variable?

Comment: pipeline variable. It's under environment variables

Comment: oh, ok. Just change single quotes in `script` to double.  Because double quotes is [GString](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)